# Docker | Create new user on fresh instance start

Tags: mysql, docker

I am currently working with Docker to create a database replication using MySQL. I need to create the user and grant replication when the Docker container starts.

I have looked on the Dockerhub for MySQL and it appears that you can copy files to a directory and then they would get executed in alphabetical order. [See here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/).

I have created a `init.sql` file which looks like this -

```
CREATE USER 'slave'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave'@'%'
```

So it literally just creates the user and then grants them replication.

However, when running this the database never starts as the sql produces the error

> mbind: Operation not permitted

So, it seems as though the `init.sql` file is running but it doesn't have permissions?

My Dockerfile is minimal and this is what it is -

```
FROM mysql:latest

COPY Docker/database/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

I have also tried to do this with as a command by doing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql --protocol=socket -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD <<EOSQL
CREATE USER 'slave'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave'@'%'
EOSQL
```

Comment: I get this error instead `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave'@'%'' at line 2`

Comment: The mbind issue is known: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/303 I think it's unrelated

Answer (score 1):

I added semicolons to the ends of the lines in your example. The mysql database now builds and runs for me.

```
CREATE USER 'slave'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave'@'%';
```

As mentioned in the comment above, the mbind error is unrelated: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/303